# 1024f invalid suffix "F" on integer constant

Tags: c++

I'm doing the excises on the book of 《C++ Primer》 5th, there is an excise on page 38,2.7

> (c) 1024f

When I run it in my computer, just like below, GCC gave me an error:

> error: invalid suffix "F" on integer constant

can someone help me to explain the reason?

```
#include<iostream>   
using namespace std;   
int main()   
{   
  cout << 1024f << endl;     
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "f" suffix stands for "Float" (`single`)

Comment: You miss the dot. Try `1024.f`

Comment: Are there a dot in the original edition?my book is Chinese edition.

Comment: @LiuGuangxuan This seems to be an error in the original book too. It should probably read either "1024" or "1024.0f". (Possibly, an ambitiuous proofreader thought "hey, 1024.0 and 1024 are the same, so I'll remove the unnecessary '.0'. Stupid programmers, they know nothing about math.")

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1024f isn't a `float` value and also not a int for example
So it can't compile. What you want to do is `1024.f`
In that way you explicitly say that the number 1024 has to be of type `float`.

```
int main() {
    cout << 1024.f << endl;
    return 0;
}
```